# How to use mongo stable api by mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my code. I can't find the way on mongodb website.

```
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true , autoIndex: false })
```

I tried to add serverApi but it didn't seems work.

```
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true , autoIndex: false , serverApi: { version: '1' } })
```

Comment: Your url?  Is that ok?

Comment: url : mongodb://localhost:27017/xxxxxx
My url should be ok

Comment: Adding this for reference: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/discussions/12875